# Full text search sort by relevancy score

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, query-optimization

**Table:** `users` with `full text search` index on column `username`.

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
    MATCH (username) AGAINST ('shaharyar' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS `score`, 
    uid, 
    first_name, 
    username, 
    `status`, 
    created
FROM users
WHERE 
    MATCH (username) AGAINST ('shaharyar' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AND 
    uid <> 164125 -- to prevent self profile search
ORDER BY 
    score DESC, 
    created DESC
```

**Question:** Will the `Match` clause execute 2 times?

I know MySQL sorts by `score` *descending* by default, but here I need double sorting condition that's why I am selecting the column.

**Explain Extended:**

```
+----+-------------+-------+----------+------------------+----------+---------+-----+------+----------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table |   type   |  possible_keys   |   key    | key_len | ref | rows | filtered |            Extra            |
+----+-------------+-------+----------+------------------+----------+---------+-----+------+----------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | fulltext | PRIMARY,username | username |       0 |     |    1 |      100 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+----------+------------------+----------+---------+-----+------+----------+-----------------------------+
```

About 150K+ records are in the table.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* so.  This is often written using a `having` clause:

```
SELECT MATCH (username) AGAINST ('shaharyar' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS `score`, 
       uid, first_name, username, `status`, created
FROM users
WHERE uid <> 164125 -- to prevent self profile search
HAVING score > 0
ORDER BY score DESC, created DESC;
```

Comment: Unfortunately your query is not using the index *(checked with Explain)*. Scanning 86K+ rows. I think its reason is that condition is not in WHERE clause but after the clause.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

`WHERE MATCH...` will be executed some number of times, thereby "filtering" out the rows that don't "match".  Only the remaining rows would need to execute the `MATCH` a second time.

`HAVING`, on the other hand, would have to perform the `MATCH` for all the rows (except for the one with that uid), build a temp table with all those rows.  Only then could the `HAVING` do the filtering.

So, even if `MATCH` is executed fewer times in the `HAVING` version, the query would probably run faster.

You *do* have `FULLTEXT(username)`, don't you?

Why, why, use a fulltext query against one word??

Comment: If I create a temp table with all the filtered rows to apply `HAVING` on them, won't it be same as my current query? Or may be I got your point wrong.. Besides its just the minimal example, I am mapping the logic to some other scenario.

Comment: That would be essentially the same as your original query -- only slower because of explicitly creating the tmp table.

Comment: It means I can say my current query is fest fit for the scenario and there is no way to get that WHERE condition in SELECT clause?